# PHP get correct IP

Tags: php, apache

My server is behind a proxy and I'm trying to get a IP of a user I'm using in PHP

```
$IP = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
```

The problem I see lately some users Ip's are like this below example Ip's.

```
173.0.0.000, 190.000.00.01
173.0.0.000, 190.000.00.02
173.0.0.000, 190.000.00.03
173.0.0.000, 190.000.00.04
173.0.0.000, 190.000.00.05
```

How would I go about just getting the correct IP like below. It doesn't happen on all the Ip's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format for `X-Forwarded-For` is: *client1, proxy1, proxy2*. So you will want to grab the first address in the list:

```
$IP = current(explode(',', $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']));

echo $IP; // 173.0.0.000
```

That will grab the first IP address whether there are multiple addresses or just one.